# Question about the way the inner stress in an axially loaded member is defined

Tags: material-science

When a member is in tension, such as in a tensile test of a piece of metal, its freebody-diagram would show a force of P in both directions.  Why then is its internal stress not $\frac{2 \cdot P}{A}$? It seems like it would be twice the force that would be straining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that a string is forming a pendulum from the ceiling: you are correct that the string exerts a downward force $-F$ on the ceiling as well as an upward force $+F$ on the ball. We have simply decided that we are going to define the stress as $F$ divided by the cross-sectional area of the string $a$, $F/a$. It is very easy to see why we care about this general combination as a material parameter: imagine if you now doubled the string, it stands to reason that you could double the weight beneath and put the material into the same situation, as you could imagine this situation essentially as two identical pendulums side-by-side. So clearly this is a much more "close-to-the-material" measure than just $F$ itself. However the combination $2F/a$ does not provide any extra physical significance as it amounts to merely defining a new unit for the same quantity. (For that matter it also has a rest-length $\ell$ and a deformation $\delta \ell$ due to the load; similar thought experiments about doubling the length of the string tell you that $\ell$ does not factor into a better account of stress than you see above, but $\delta \ell/\ell$, the strain, is much closer to the material than either $\ell$ or $\delta \ell$ themselves.)

Meanwhile yes, if you look microscopically you will see a lot of miniature volumes which are pulled upward by force $F$ and also downward by force $-F$, balancing out to 0, to keep it from accelerating upward or downward. If you want to treat this as a "substring" with the above definition of tension, then you will regard its "local stress" as being $|F|/a.$

You can define it with an extra factor of 2 in it, but this like all unit systems is just a social convention and if you want to read the scientific tables that everyone else uses, you're going to have to use a unit conversion to accommodate the different conventions -- just the same as when you're reading one of those obnoxious fluid dynamics tables that uses diameters instead of radii. They chose how to report their measurements; you choose how to perform your calculations; if your units are not defined identically then you must perform a conversion step between the two.

Comment: Thanks for that great response, it cleared it up for me.
I have another related question though:
Say we have two different forces pulling something, say a force of P in one way, and a force of F in the other direction.  If $F<P$ does that mean that the $\sigma = F/A$?

Comment: @Lerbi: No. In fact if the forces do not balance then the thing is accelerating and possibly deforming. On the assumption that the deformation reaches a steady state in the accelerated reference frame, the acceleration $a = (P - F)/m$ allows the stress to not be uniform throughout the object, but rather it will decrease linearly from $P/A$ at the one side to $F/A$ at the other side due to the fictitious force $a~d\mu$ present on any mass $d\mu$ in the accelerated frame. The average stress, which is the stress exactly in the middle, is $(P + F)/(2A)$ for example.